# ImageRestyle yielding low-level errors even in example cases

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

the title covers it. I'm on v11.3.0.0 on a MacBook Pro running Mojave 10.14.2, and trying to run ImageRestyle seems to immediately throw a bunch of errors that aren't related to the input in an obvious way. This happens even with the examples given in the documentation, and then the input just hangs—it's not clear if it's successfully doing anything or not, but I've left it for quite a while (~1 hour) with no results.

I'll include a screenshot, because the input is literally just defining two images, `i` and `s`, and saying: `ImageRestyle[i,s,PerformanceGoal->"Speed"]`.

[image]

Is there something obvious that I'm missing here? I can't see it, and I couldn't find any similar errors when searching either here or google.

Comment: Can you try `ImageRestyle[RandomImage[], RandomImage[], PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]`? It's possible there's an issue with the color space of your images or something.

Comment: You've been here for a while, you are supposed to know that the [tag:bugs] tag should not be added until what you have has been reproduced by other users.

Comment: All of the examples in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageRestyle.html), including your example which is from the "Possible Issues" section, work fine for me on Mac OS Mojave 10.14.2, Mathematica 11.3.

Comment: J.M.iscomputer-less: my bad; I actually haven't come across that either personally or in the context of another user before.

@CarlLange that was my first thought, so I confirmed that the color spaces were the same, and even resized the images to the same dimensions even though it seemed from the documentation that that shouldn't matter. The suggested code returns the same series of errors.

Comment: @BenKalziqi OK - I would probably recommend contacting WRI support. You may also consider running `PacletUpdate["NeuralFunctions"]`, and perhaps trying `PerformanceGoal->"Quality"` might work, since it uses a different network. Lastly, if you need image restyling right now, you could try using this network: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/AdaIN-Style-Trained-on-MS-COCO-and-Painter-by-Numbers-Data.